# DomCrawler, selecting class in specific position with first() or last() or eq()

Tags: php, web-scraping, domcrawler

I am a bit confused about selecting one `class` between it's siblings... `Html` structure like below.

```
<ul class="pipeLink">
  <li class="pg">1</li><li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=2&amp;tdfkn=14">2</a></li>
  <li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=3&amp;tdfkn=14">3</a></li>
  <li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=4&amp;tdfkn=14">4</a></li>
  <li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=5&amp;tdfkn=14">5</a></li>
  <li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=6&amp;tdfkn=14">6</a></li>
  <li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=7&amp;tdfkn=14">7</a></li>
  <li class="pg"><a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=8&amp;tdfkn=14">8</a></li>
  <li class="lastChild">
      <a href="/wedding/clientList/?pn=2&amp;tdfkn=14">next 30</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are 2 `ul.pipeLine` class in the page. On the top of the page and bottom. I just want to grab first or second `ul.pipeLine` and iterate the a tag's attribute in it. So I tried it with the code below.

```
$links = $response->filter("ul.pipeLink")->last()->each(function($node){
    return $node->filter("li a")->attr("href");
});
```

But when I use `last()` or `first()` or `eq(0)` etc... it's only getting one attribute inside the a tag, nothing else. Although I wanted to grab only one `ul.pipeLine` class in the page and iterate inside it.

I mean expected output should be like:

```
/wedding/clientList/?pn=2&amp;tdfkn=14
/wedding/clientList/?pn=3&amp;tdfkn=14
/wedding/clientList/?pn=4&amp;tdfkn=14
/wedding/clientList/?pn=5&amp;tdfkn=14
/wedding/clientList/?pn=6&amp;tdfkn=14
/wedding/clientList/?pn=7&amp;tdfkn=14
/wedding/clientList/?pn=8&amp;tdfkn=14
```

But it's like:

```
/wedding/clientList/?pn=2&amp;tdfkn=14
```

Is it possible to make it happen?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I solved the problem and posting it here as an answer for anyone who face this later.

```
$links = $response->filter("ul.pipeLink")->last()->children("li a")->each(function($node){
    return $node->attr("href");
});
```